# How can I make my owl carousel direction follow the mouse wheel direction

Tags: carousel, owl-carousel, mousewheel

When i scroll mouse wheel it moves but when i change scrolling direction it does not change its direction.
How can i make my owl carousel direction follow the mouse wheel direction ?
When i scroll mouse wheel it moves but when i change scrolling direction it does not change its direction.
How can i make my owl carousel direction follow the mouse wheel direction ?

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    responsiveClass: true,
    rtl: false,
    stagePadding: 100,
    smartSpeed: 550,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 1000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    nav: true,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
            nav: true
        },
        600: {
            items: 3,
            nav: true
        },
        1000: {
            items: 5,
            nav: true,
            
        }
    }
})
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        owl.trigger('next.owl');
    } else {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
html{
            width: 100vw;
            background: linear-gradient(0deg,#aaaaaa,#f0f0f0) no-repeat;
        }
    .demo-container{
        margin-top: 5em;
        background: linear-gradient(0deg,#aaaaaa,#f0f0f0);
    }
    .owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer{
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .sb-carousel-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sb-carousel-wrap .brand-carousel-gradient {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 105px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.brand-carousel-gradient.left {
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), #fbfbfb);
}
.brand-carousel-gradient.right {
    right: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0), #fbfbfb);
}
.sb-car-img{
 overflow: hidden;
}
.sb-car-img:hover img{
     transform: scale(1.2);
}

.sb-itm-img  {
   transition: all 0.6s ease-in 0s;
 -webkit-transition:  all 0.6s ease-in 0s;
 -ms-transition:  all 0.6s ease-in 0s;
}
.my-slider{
 float: left:
 width:100%;
 padding: 0 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-slider">
<div class="sb-carousel-wrap">
        <div class="brand-carousel-gradient left"></div>
        <div class="brand-carousel-gradient right"></div>
       <div class="demo-container">
         <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    
            <div class="item">
                <div class="sb-car-img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/923361/pexels-photo-923361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="sb-itm-img" alt="">
                </div>
             </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="sb-car-img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/923361/pexels-photo-923361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="sb-itm-img" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="sb-car-img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/923361/pexels-photo-923361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="sb-itm-img" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="sb-car-img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/923361/pexels-photo-923361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="sb-itm-img" alt="">
                </div>
    
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="sb-car-img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/923361/pexels-photo-923361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="sb-itm-img" alt="">
                </div>
    
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="sb-car-img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/923361/pexels-photo-923361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="sb-itm-img" alt="">
                </div>
    
    
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="sb-car-img">
                    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/923361/pexels-photo-923361.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="sb-itm-img" alt="">
                </div>
    
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

In Chrome developer tools (F12), inspect the wheel event with a log:

`console.log(e);`

This will show you that `e.deltaY` does not exist in the event object. However, the property `e.originalEvent` does, and `e.originalEvent.deltaY` exists here.

Therefore, change the callback to this:

```
    ...
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
    ...
```

The scroll should work correctly in both directions now.

[edit] I looked into getting it working in IE(11). IE11 shows the wheel event object property `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta` which is not present in the Chrome object, and this can be used in the same way as `deltaY`.

In this case, we can use

```
    ...
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta> 0) {
    ...
```

and it should work on both Chrome and IE11.

To get this working in Firefox as well, a different callback event AND property is needed:

Callback is `DOMMouseScroll` and property to test is `e.originalEvent.detail`, as follows:

```
owl.on('DOMMouseScroll','.owl-stage',function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0){
        owl.trigger('next.owl');
    } 
    else {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

As a side note, I looked at the Owl demo, and this does indeed run as described in the documentation, using e.deltaY.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
To solve this problem simply replace:

```
if (e.deltaY > 0) {
```

with:

```
if (e.originalEvent.deltaY>0){
```